# how to can insert the value from txt file to the Qlist and work with QTablewideget

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qlist, qtabwidget

how i can to insert the value from txt file in to the Qlist...

```
    QList<QString> list_StRead;
    list_StRead.insert();
```

i can sorting txt file ...
its mean that my file is a line by line...
than after the insert to the Qlist i want to write in to Qtabelewidget...
how i must to do??
 u must to be completely understand.. see the img file ..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdhKv.png)

tnx for all....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <QStringList>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

int main(void)
{
  QFile data("data.txt");
  QTextStream stream(&data);
  QStringList strings(stream.readAll().split("\n")); // or another split character
}
```